# Find $A$ if $2\sin(4A)=1$ ($A$ lies between $0^{\circ}$ and $180^{\circ}$)

Tags: trigonometry

I approached this problem like this:

$$\begin{aligned}2\sin(4A)=&\ 1\\
\sin(4A)=&\ 1/2 \\
4A=&\ 30^{\circ}\\
A=&\ 7.5^{\circ}
\end{aligned}$$
But answer says there are two possible values i.e., $7.5^{\circ}$ and $30^{\circ}.$

Please help me out, how is it $30$ degrees?

Comment: $4A$ could also be $150^\circ$. But $A$ cannot be $30^\circ$.

Comment: Just first consider values of $x$ such that $0\leq x\leq \pi$ and $\sin(x)=\frac{1}{2}$. Try graphing the sine wave on this interval.

Comment: @Dave sorry but I am still in 10th grade. Can you share an alternate method which only involves degrees and not radians?

Answer (score 1):

$2\sin(4A^\circ)=1$ implies $\sin(4A^\circ)=1/2$, which implies

$$
4A\in\{30+360m,150+360n\}
$$

which means

$$
A\in\{7.5+90m,75+90n\}
$$

Because $A\in[0,180]$, we have $m,n\in\{0,1\}$, which indicates that

$$
A\in\{7.5,97.5,75,165\}
$$

> But answer says there are two possible values i.e., 7.5 and 30.

I doubt the correctness of this answer

Comment: Can you please clarify how did you define that 4A∈{30+360m,150+360n}?

Comment: Generally, if we say $x\in\{a,b,c\}$ then $x$ should be one of $a$, $b$, or $c$.

Comment: Sorry but I think you didn't get me. I wanted to ask how and why did you express 4A as a linear combination(30+360m and 150+360n).

Comment: @Dhairya Sine is a periodic function with a period size of 360, so $\sin(30^\circ+360^\circ m)=\sin(30^\circ)$ where $m$ is some integer